# Tenho um arquivo(não é txt) e quero abrir esse arquivo sem a necessidade do usuário clicar

Tags: javascript

Sou iniciante e estou com dúvidas.
Segue exemplo de como quero que seja:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- Como fazer esse link abrir sem necessidade do usuário clicar?-->
    <a href="launch.jnlp">Clique</a>

</body>
```

Comment: Queres que o browser vá automáticamente para outra página ou queres abrir uma nova janela/tab com esse link?

Comment: Rapaz, esse jnlp é um java web start. tem um applet acoplado aí

Comment: Ao clicar ele abre fora do navegador não precisa ser dentro no navegador, isso vai abrir uma ova página.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quiser abrir o link em uma nova tab, embora você seja iniciante, pode optar por **JavaScript** , segue um **exemplo prático:**

```
function OpenInNewTab(url) {
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
win.focus();
}
```

No código **HTML** apenas iremos colocar:

```
<body onload=OpenInNewtab('http.....')>
.......
</body>
```

Comment: Sim, esqueci de dizer quero fazer isso com javascript

Comment: Deu certo aqui. Vcs manjam muito

Comment: Qualquer dúvida disponha :)